# Convert array of strings to comma separate strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given an array like: `['a', 'b']`

I want to get `'a','b'` - This is because I want to insert that result into a `IN` sql query. I have tried `myVar.join(',')` but that returns `'a,b'` not `'a', 'b'`.

Comment: `because I want to insert that result into a IN sql query`  be careful of SQL injection then.  Most sql library's have query params to prevent this.

Comment: Performing SQL queries using javascript? Humph... Are you sure you're not sending this data to a server side script / handler which actually performs the SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Just use map to put quotes on each elements then join.

```js
    console.log(['a','b'].map(a=>"'"+a+"'").join(","))
```

learn all the Array methods here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

You could [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to add the quotes and then [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the results:

```js
let arr =  ['a', 'b']
console.log(arr.map(l => `'${l}'`).join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6/ES2015, you can go:

```
const myQuery = `'${myVar.join("','")}'`;
```

Comment: Won't this quote the whole string rather than each letter?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry, just made an edit, adding the double quotes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
var array = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(convertArray(array));
function convertArray(arr){
  var str = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(i+1<arr.length){
   str += "'"+arr[i]+"',";
   } else {
    str += "'"+arr[i]+"'";
   }
   }
   return str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, is not so elegant but it works..

```
var letters = ['a', 'b'];
letters = '\''+letters.join('\',\'')+'\'';
alert(letters);
```